# Array length número menor que o correto - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando um array, onde ao dar um `console.log` o mesmo mostra 2 itens dentro, logo abaixo em outro `console.log` com `length` ele marca 1, mas o certo é ele ter 2 itens no array.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
console.log(av)
console.log(av.length)
```

Anteriormente, utilizando a função `slice()`, ela repetia todos os arrays ao dar um `push()`. Daí tive que obtar um usar o `for()`.

No exemplo acima a variável é global.

Comment: Na propria imagem indica `length:2`. Se lhe aparece `1` é porque qualquer coisa no meio mexeu no array

Comment: Coloca o código aqui pra gente por favor

Comment: @Isac O console.log esta uma embaixo do outro (linha: 462 e 463)... Eu desconfio que um dos problemas é por não aparecer [array(124)][Array(123)] no título.

Comment: @BrunoMorales  O código é bem grande, amanhã irei destrinchá-lo e tentar postar parte dele...

Comment: Oi @abcd! Eu acho que esta pergunta é respondida por outra que marquei agora. Basicamente o que o browser mostra na consola é alterado depois do momento em que o `console.log` corre, porque é uma array/ponteiro para o original. Se fizeres `console.log(JSON.stringify(av));` o resultado já vai ser o esperado.

Comment: @Sergio Obrigado, era isso mesmo,abaixo no `console.log`havia um push. E era isso que ele estava fazendo. ATT